# How do I pass a variable to my scripts .js file?

Tags: javascript

This is in my head:

```
<script>
var uid = "<?=$uid;?>";
</script>
```

I need to use "uid" on my .js file but I don't know how. Is there an easy way to retrieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your put that `<script>` before your `<script src="">` that links to your `.js` file, the variable is within scope in that file. However, any page that does not declare the `uid` variable but references that script file will error.

Remember, the variable has to be declared before a separate file can use it:

```
<script>
var uid = "<?=$uid;?>";
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use it anywhere, just make sure this block is before you load any external javascript files.